# Django: How to handle error at custom form_valid() correctly

Tags: python, django, error-handling, django-forms

What is the "correct" way on handle errors inside a custom form_valid() function?

E.g. I'm having a view which is having this form_valid() method defined:

```
class StorageItemMergeView(FormView):
# ...

def form_valid(self, form):
    si = StorageItem.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs["pk"])
    si.part.merge_storage_items(si, StorageItem.objects.get(
                                  pk=self.request.POST["storageitem1"]
                                  )
                               )
    return super(StorageItemMergeView, self).form_valid(form)
```

The form for this is quiet minimal:

```
class MergeStorageItemsForm(forms.Form):
    storageitem1 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=StorageItem.objects.all())
```

As a matter of fact the user might fill in syntactical correct data which are failing at call of merge_storage_items().

In my case merge_storage_items() is able to return True or False -- but how to react correctly in case of the method call is failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way is not to do it in form_valid at all. That's not what it's for. That method is called one the form has been validated and is responsible for saving and redirecting.

The right place to do this is in the form class itself, where you would override the `clean` method and raise `forms.ValidationError` if the check fails.

Comment: Actually in my case the principal validation of input is correct. But wodering how to react if $action based on valid input is failing

Comment: Actually after playing around it appears to be a good hint anyway. The logic is now done on model level in my case and is raising exception.

Comment: What if there's something beyond the form validation that goes wrong? LIke, during save Postgres fails for some reason, or an email is sent but it fals, or you process the information against some third party endpoint (a payment or a delivery i.e.), and it fails? Or even, you are merging in a single form fields that belong to 2 different models so you save part of the info in one and then the other one, etc. I'm facing a situation similar to these examples and it's driving me crazy to try to understand the right place for each piece..

Comment: @PerePicornell I ran into the same issue. You could call `self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())` then apply conditional context and template logic based on the results. An example of this is in [django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetConfirmView](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/auth/views.py). Although in the example that method is called from `dispatch` not `form_valid`, it works from `form_valid` as well.